Why PHPMailer is not sending an email on InfinityFree?
I'm having trouble sending emails using PHPMailer on my website hosted on InfinityFree. When I try to send an email, I encounter an HTTP Error 500 without any other useful error message. I've reviewed the code, but I cannot pinpoint the issue.
The code uses PHPMailer to send an email when a user submits their email address. Here's the code I'm using:
require 'phpmailer/vendor/autoload.php';
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

function send_live_album_email($email, $album_url, $qr_code_file) {
    return send_qr_email($email, $album_url, $qr_code_file, "Live Album Access");
}

function send_longterm_album_email($email, $album_url) {
    $qr_code_file = "";
    return send_qr_email($email, $album_url, $qr_code_file, "Long-term Album Access");
}

function send_qr_email($email, $album_url, $qr_code_file) {
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Username = "my_email"; // email censored
    $mail->Password = "my_password"; // password censored
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->AddAddress($email);
    $mail->setFrom("my_email", "Photo Album Access | Photographer App");
    // Subject and Body
    $mail->Subject = "Photographer | Photo Album QR Code";
    $qr_code_image_url = "url_here" . htmlspecialchars($qr_code_file ?? ''); //url censored
    $email_template = "
        <h2>Hello!</h2>
        <p>Here is your link to access the photo album:</p>
        <p><a type='button' class='btn btn-primary' href='$album_url'>Click here to view album</a></p>
        <br><br>
        <p>Regards,</p>
        <h4>Photographer App</h4>
    ";
    $mail->Body = $email_template;
    $mail->AltBody = strip_tags($email_template);
    try {
        $mail->send();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['send_email'])) {
    $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $album_url = "url_here"; // url censored
    if ($isLive) {
        if ($qr_code_file) {
            if (send_live_album_email($email, $album_url, $qr_code_file)) {
            echo "<script>alert('Live album sent successfully!');</script>";
        } else {
            echo "<script>alert('Failed to send live album email.');</script>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('QR code not available for live album.');</script>";
    }
} else {
    if (send_longterm_album_email($email, $album_url)) {
        echo "<script>alert('Album email sent successfully!');</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Failed to send long-term album email.');</script>";
    }
  }
}

<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email here" required>
    </div>
    <button name="send_email" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

These codes are on just one file.

"I encounter an HTTP Error 500 without any other useful error message" - deliberately, because this is not supposed to give internals away to website visitors. You need to go and check what your error log has to say.

Aside for checking error logs to see the actual problem, beware that your script explicitly catches any exception thrown and discards the error message, and it also runs PHPMailer with debug mode disabled, which is fine for Production but might be worth enabling to diagnose problems.
